# Postgres - Create columns from multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rows

I'm new to the forum but have been using it exstesively from Google searches. I'd like to thank all who contribute and have contributed to this very helpful forum. I hope to one day help other members in need myself.

I'm fairly new to SQL so I may be a little rough with even asking the question; but here it goes;

I'm wanting to create multiple result columns from multiple rows.Example below.

```
User_ID    classification       date_classified
123456      crazy               20110120
123456      loud                20100120
123456      absurd              20120120
123456      insane              20140120
654321      quiet               20130120
654321      reserved            20000120
654321      slow                19990120
654321      accurate            19950120
```

From this, I only want one row for each user.

```
User_ID    classification_1     classification_1    classification_1    classification_1    
123456      crazy               loud                absurd              insane
654321      quiet               reserved            slow                accurate
```

Comment: So you want to turn your current results, which have multiple rows for each classification, into one long result per user_id?  Just curious why you can't process this afterwards instead of inside the  query itself.

Comment: You can use `crosstab` function. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html